# Common subexpression elimination OpenCL

Tags: opencl, nvidia, compiler-optimization

I have a very large kernel which uses ~1000 temporary variables to compute ~1000 equations. So it is safe to assume that all of the temporary variables will be put in private off-chip memory aka CUDA __local memory (i know it's bad, but there is no other way).

My question is if common subexpressions are eliminated between neighboring lines like these:

```
const float t747 = t472*t28*t26*t715*t30*t11;
const float t748 = t472*t28*t717*t26*t30*t11;
```

As you can see the only difference is variable t717 versus t715. The question is if those two lines translate into 7 or 12 global loads?

Because if the target compiler (Nvidia Kepler GPU in my case) does not use registers to cache common subexpressions between lines i'm gonna need to implement it myself.

Note: All code is generated automatically, so manual tuning won't be possible.

EDIT: All t0-t999 variables are declared as "const float".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilers translate all the global reads as direct reads. So, in your case **12** reads.

This is due to the fact that the **global memory is considered as volatile memory**, and caching is not possible. However, if you simply do this: (I think you know it, but anyway...)

```
const float temp = t472*t28*t26*t30*t11;
const float t747 = temp*t715;
const float t748 = temp*t717;
```

The compiler will translate that into 7 global reads.

*NOTE: At least this was valid with old arquitectures, I dunno if there is some new compiler/arquitecture that can cleverly detect these cases and optimize them.*

Comment: Do you think that -cl-strict-aliasing and/or -cl-fast-relaxed-math compiler flags would change anything?

Comment: And regarding "global memory is considered as volatile memory": yes it is global memory in hardware, but still private memory in software. So no other thread should be able to modify it, which would make it non-volatile. At least from my point of view, what the compiler thinks i don't know.